# Background thread created in http handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I was looking at the code my developers wrote. On one of the Http handlers, they receives multiple long IO requests, which they schedule by create Threads manually for each request and scheduling it instead of using ThreadPool. It makes sense to not queue these requests on ThreadPool as it might eat up the threads meant to serve web requests.

Not my question is, if I create a background thread in handler and my application doesn't receive any other http request for the idle time defined to kill the worker process. Then my worker process will be killed and what will happen to those threads?

Will they also get terminated because they were not marked as foreground thread?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. They're all part of the same application domain that dies with the worker process. With a normal `Thread` if not marked as `IsBackground` it will basically hold the process open until it completes.

If you have overlapping worker processes enabled (true by default) this isn't a problem for new requests coming in as a new process will start, but if you have it turned off it will wait  until the existing one quits, basically halting the site.

So really if you want them to live longer you either have to increase timeouts or have them handled by some external process using IPC etc.